# Job being executed twice using Rails, Active Job, Sidekiq, Clockwork, Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq, clockwork

Using the stack outlined, my jobs are running twice and I can't figure out why. Everything seems to work as planned when testing locally. I'm using a separate process to run `bundle exec clockwork clock.rb`

**clock.rb**

```
require 'clockwork'
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

module Clockwork

    configure do |config|
        # set timezone to central time
        config[:tz] = 'America/Chicago'
    end

    every(1.day, "SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob", at: '08:00') do
        SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob.perform_later
    end 

    every(1.day, "CreateWarehouseInvoicesForCustomersJob", at: '20:00', if: lambda { |t| t.day == 1 }) do
        CreateWarehouseInvoicesForCustomersJob.perform_later
    end

end
```

**Example Job:**

```
class SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  DAYS_OVERDUE_TRIGGER = 3

  def perform(*args)
        overdue_invoices = Invoice.overdue.where(overdue_reminder_sent: false)

        overdue_invoices.each do |inv|
            days_overdue = (Date.today() - inv.due_date.to_date).to_i

            if (days_overdue > DAYS_OVERDUE_TRIGGER)
                finance_contacts = inv.manufacturing_order.contacts.joins(:document_types).where("contacts.is_active": true, "document_types.code": :invoice)

                emails_string = finance_contacts.collect(&:email).join(",")

                if emails_string.present?
                    inv.overdue_reminder_sent = true;
                    if inv.save
                        InvoiceMailer.send_overdue_reminder(emails_string, inv.id).deliver_later
                    end
                else # send notification that contacts are missing from projects
                    InvoiceMailer.send_missing_contacts_notification(inv.id).deliver_later
                end
            end
        end
  end
end
```

I was previously using Heroku Scheduler, then removed the addon. Here is the result of heroku ps:

```
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.1 to 8.1.3.
=== scheduler (Basic): bundle exec clockwork clock.rb (1)
scheduler.1: up 2023/05/25 11:00:36 -0500 (~ 2h ago)

=== sidekiqworker (Basic): bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q default -q mailers (1)
sidekiqworker.1: up 2023/05/25 11:00:44 -0500 (~ 2h ago)

=== web (Basic): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV (1)
web.1: up 2023/05/25 11:00:47 -0500 (~ 2h ago)
```

**Heroku Logs**

```
May 30 06:00:01 app app/sidekiqworker.1 D, [2023-05-30T13:00:01.314428 #2] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob] [5478e192-3f00-4808-a6c6-9770feffc7a6]   TRANSACTION (2.7ms)  COMMIT
May 30 06:00:01 app app/sidekiqworker.1 I, [2023-05-30T13:00:01.327844 #2]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob] [5478e192-3f00-4808-a6c6-9770feffc7a6] Enqueued ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: "InvoiceMailer", "send_overdue_reminder", "deliver_now", {:args=>["customer@test.com,customer2@test.com,customer3@test.com", 12204]}
May 30 06:00:01 app app/sidekiqworker.1 I, [2023-05-30T13:00:01.328481 #2]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob] [5478e192-3f00-4808-a6c6-9770feffc7a6] Performed SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob (Job ID: 5478e192-3f00-4808-a6c6-9770feffc7a6) from Sidekiq(default) in 690.84ms
May 30 06:00:01 app app/sidekiqworker.1 2 TID-10kq SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob JID-880ee11a0fb55b07c7cbd300 INFO: done: 0.732 sec
May 30 06:00:01 app app/sidekiqworker.1 I, [2023-05-30T13:00:01.328268 #2]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef] Performing ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob (Job ID: 1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef) from Sidekiq(default) enqueued at 2023-05-30T13:00:01Z with arguments: "InvoiceMailer", "send_overdue_reminder", "deliver_now", {:args=>["customer1@test.com,customer2@test.com,customer3@test.com", 12204]}
May 30 06:00:03 app app/sidekiqworker.1 D, [2023-05-30T13:00:03.385487 #2] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef]   Rendering invoice_mailer/send_overdue_reminder.html.erb within layouts/mailer
May 30 06:00:03 app app/sidekiqworker.1 I, [2023-05-30T13:00:03.386305 #2]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef]   Rendered invoice_mailer/send_overdue_reminder.html.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.8ms | Allocations: 81)
May 30 06:00:03 app app/sidekiqworker.1 D, [2023-05-30T13:00:03.388852 #2] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef]   Rendering invoice_mailer/send_overdue_reminder.text.erb within layouts/mailer
May 30 06:00:03 app app/sidekiqworker.1 I, [2023-05-30T13:00:03.389753 #2]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef]   Rendered invoice_mailer/send_overdue_reminder.text.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 78)
May 30 06:00:03 app app/sidekiqworker.1 D, [2023-05-30T13:00:03.394141 #2] DEBUG -- : [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob] [1d9e1441-fcec-465b-a942-94ef4e1fbaef] InvoiceMailer#send_overdue_reminder: processed outbound mail in 2064.7ms
May 30 06:00:09 app app/sidekiqworker.1     We're just giving you a friendly reminder that the attached invoice is overdue.
```

Logs - Action Mailer Exception

```
{
  "context": "Job raised exception",
  "job": {
    "class": "ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper",
    "wrapped": "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob",
    "queue": "default",
    "args": [
      {
        "job_class": "ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob",
        "job_id": "d34397b9-0f74-4894-980c-dccc783b0f40",
        "provider_job_id": null,
        "queue_name": "default",
        "priority": null,
        "arguments": [
          "InvoiceMailer",
          "send_overdue_reminder",
          "deliver_now",
          {
            "args": [
              "customer1@test.com",
              12199
            ],
            "_aj_ruby2_keywords": [
              "args"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "executions": 0,
        "exception_executions": {},
        "locale": "en",
        "timezone": "Central Time (US & Canada)",
        "enqueued_at": "2023-05-29T13:00:00Z"
      }
    ],
    "retry": true,
    "jid": "05324bdf6fd2aedb9e65c480",
    "created_at": 1685365200.5488749,
    "enqueued_at": 1685365200.5489137
  },
  "jobstr": "{\"class\":\"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper\",\"wrapped\":\"ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob\",\"queue\":\"default\",\"args\":[{\"job_class\":\"ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob\",\"job_id\":\"d34397b9-0f74-4894-980c-dccc783b0f40\",\"provider_job_id\":null,\"queue_name\":\"default\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":[\"InvoiceMailer\",\"send_overdue_reminder\",\"deliver_now\",{\"args\":[\"customer1@test.com\",12199],\"_aj_ruby2_keywords\":[\"args\"]}],\"executions\":0,\"exception_executions\":{},\"locale\":\"en\",\"timezone\":\"Central Time (US & Canada)\",\"enqueued_at\":\"2023-05-29T13:00:00Z\"}],\"retry\":true,\"jid\":\"05324bdf6fd2aedb9e65c480\",\"created_at\":1685365200.5488749,\"enqueued_at\":1685365200.5489137}"
}
```

Why might the job be executing twice?

Comment: Are your jobs running twice or being created twice? How many workers do you have running?

Comment: @dbugger what's a good way to determine this? I thought the heroku ps shows how many workers are running for a given process; showing 1 for the scheduler process.

Comment: Not the workers -- the job object it self -- is your code creating it twice? Is  SendInvoiceOverdueRemindersJob.perform_later getting called twice?

Comment: @dbugger, looking at the logs on Heroku, it seems to only trigger the job one time. Is there another way I can see if the job is getting performed twice?

Comment: @dbugger also for a little more diagnostic info: there are multiple jobs that are all performed twice. FYI - a little more context, by "running twice" I'm getting duplicate emails which the job sends out.

Comment: @dbugger look at the log entries I added to my post showing logs for action mailer sending twice.

Comment: The log looks like it is rendering the html version and the text version of the email -- is that what you mean by "Sending it twice?"

Comment: ... I deleted my comment cause it was not accurate. Let me do some log investigation.

Comment: @dbugger The logs don't show multiple jobs being triggered from what I can tell. Here is my Procfile command: `sidekiqworker bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q default -q mailers`

Comment: @dbugger wanted to let you know that suddenly there are no duplicate emails. I did not change any code, so I'm wondering if somehow somewhere in the Heroku infrastructure it's possible it was causing it and it since reset and resolved itself. I'm not sure - a mystery...